# ¿Como puedo arreglar mi grafica de barras en Django de cantidad de OT por mes y año en chart.js?

Tags: javascript, html, python, chart.js

este es mi codigo para generar el grafico de barras en chart.js, pero las etiquetas de los meses se desacomodan y no se alinean con mis barras. Estoy obteniendo los datos de mi modelo ots que tiene el campo ot y el campo finfecha.

```
    def grafico_barras(request):
        data = ots.objects.annotate(month=ExtractMonth('finfecha'),year=ExtractYear('finfecha')).values('month', 'year').annotate(count=Count('ot'))

        categories = []
        series_data = []

        for entry in data:
            month_name = calendar.month_name[entry['month']]
            category = f"{month_name} {entry['year']}"
            categories.append(category)
            series_data.append(entry['count'])

        context = {
            'categories': categories,
            'series_data': series_data,
        }

        return render(request, 'cmmsapp/grafico_barras.html', context)
```

Aqui estoy llamando las variables desde mi vista

```
        <script>
                // varibales que se obtienen de la vista
                var categories = "{{ categories|safe }}"; 
                var series_data = "{{ series_data|safe }}";
```

Aqui ya estoy generando el grafico de barras

```
                var ctx = document.getElementById('graficoBarras').getContext('2d');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: categories,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'OTs por Mes',
                            data: series_data,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            categoryPercentage: 0.8,  // Controla el ancho de las barras
                            barPercentage: 0.9  // Controla el espacio entre las barras
                        }]
                    },
```

Aqui le estoy dando las opciones uqe tendra mi grafico

```
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            x: {
                                type: 'category',
                                grid: {
                                    drawOnChartArea: false
                                }
                            },
                            y: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                ticks: {
                                    precision: 0  // Configura la precisión del eje y a 0 para evitar decimales
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    
        </script>
```

[image: las barras no estan alinedas con los meses]